# setting bitmapimage uri source

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I want to set the `UriSource` of `BitmapImage` for image that is added to my project.

```
  BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/"
           + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
           + ";component/"
           + "5.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

so is thr any package that i have to install or what..
exception

"SystemNotSupported Exception"

Comment: Can you give the detail of the entire exception? Are you doing it in the application or past of the Test Project?

Comment: Have you set the Build type to 'Resource' for the 5.jpg file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is due to bad metadata in the image.
Look this
 http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/07/exceptions_thrown_by_bitmapimage_and_bitmapframe.html 
for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Hope it will work.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(imageRequestUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(uri);
```